# jquery .toggle on the same div but only open one

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

```
<div>
    <input class='kommentareBtn' type='button' value='Kommentare'>
    <div class='blogKommentare'>Halooooooooooo</div>
</div>

<div>
    <input class='kommentareBtn' type='button' value='Kommentare'>
    <div class='blogKommentare'>Halooooooooooo</div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".kommentareBtn").click(function () {
        $(".blogKommentare").toggle();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xum1zfqo/

I want that if open the field `.blogKommentare` when I click on the button `.kommentareBtn` but only the one field under the button and not all of the fields.

Comment: Your jsFiddle code doesn't make sense... IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Why shouldn't this make sense?

Comment: You should definitively create the relevant "opened" and "closed" class. It would help you a lot when handling event on the related button.

Comment: @BlueRedONe Your posted question use classes while your jsFiddle use IDs and btw you didn't include jQuery in jsFiddle

Comment: Can you show me this in jsfiddle?

Comment: Ouu sorry i posted the wrong one..

Comment: @BlueRedOne - here (also edited my answer to include this): https://jsfiddle.net/xum1zfqo/9/

Comment: @LukyTwomey I had this already but thank you

Comment: I accepted you'r anwser beacuse it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toggle() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9. if you are using 1.8 below code will work

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".kommentareBtn").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".blogKommentare").toggle();
        });
    });
```

See fiddle here:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/xum1zfqo/9/
```

Comment: Indeed they must, missed that thanks. Looks like I was beaten to edit my code too lol, thanks Guy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, but its will work only on your example of html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".kommentareBtn").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".blogKommentare").first().toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#kommentareBtn").click(function(){
        $(this).next("#blogKommentare").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xum1zfqo/7/)

[More Example see the Link](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)